# Is passing a pointer by reference the correct way to do this?

Tags: c++, oop, function, pointers, reference

This is my function:

```
void CreateRenderTarget(HWND, ID2D1HwndRenderTarget*);
```

and there is how it works:

```
void D2DRes::CreateRenderTarget(HWND hwnd, ID2D1HwndRenderTarget* pRT)
{
    RECT rc;
    GetClientRect(hwnd,&rc);

    pFactory->CreateHwndRenderTarget(
            D2D1::RenderTargetProperties(),
            D2D1::HwndRenderTargetProperties(
                hwnd,
                D2D1::SizeU(
                    rc.right - rc.left,
                    rc.bottom - rc.top)),
                &pRT);
}
```

It is called like this:

```
pD2DRes->CreateRenderTarget(map.GetHWnd(),map.GetpRT());
```

Once returning from CreateRenderTarget(), map.pRT is NULL. How comes?

**Edit**: There is my GetpRT() function:

```
ID2D1HwndRenderTarget* MapEditor::GetpRT()
{
    return pRT;
}
```

Comment: What's the definition of `GetpRT`?

Comment: ID2D1HwndRenderTarget* MapEditor::GetpRT()
{
 return pRT;
}

pRT a private ID2D1HwndRenderTarget* in my map object.

Comment: map.GetpRT() must also return a **reference** to its pRT pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First problem:**

> Once returning from `CreateRenderTarget()`, `map.pRT` is `NULL`. How comes?

Because you are not passing the pointer *by reference*. In order to pass it by reference, the signature of `CreateRenderTarget()` should be:

```
void CreateRenderTarget(HWND, ID2D1HwndRenderTarget*&);
//                                                  ^
```

Unless you do that, your `CreateRenderTarget()` would be working on a *copy* of the pointer passed as an argument, and changes to its value won't affect the original pointer.

**Second problem:**

You write:

> [...] There is my `GetpRT()` function:
>
> ```
> ID2D1HwndRenderTarget* MapEditor::GetpRT()
> {
>     return pRT;
> }
> ```

Notice, that `GetpRT` should also return a *reference* to the internal `pRT` pointer, otherwise the above change won't have an effect (you would be passing by reference a *copy* of the original `pRT`.

Therefore, you should modify its signature accordingly:

```
ID2D1HwndRenderTarget*& MapEditor::GetpRT()
//                    ^
{
    return pRT;
}
```

Comment: @MickaelBergeronNéron: You're welcome, good luck with your project :)

Comment: ID2D1HwndRenderTarget*& MapEditor::GetRefpRT()
{
 return &pRT;
}

What is wrong there?

Comment: @MickaelBergeronNéron: If `pRT` has type `ID2D1HwndRenderTarget*`, then the function should just do `return pRT;`, not `return &pRT;` (otherwise you are returning a *pointer to* a pointer.

Comment: @MickaelBergeronNéron: What do you mean by "wouldn't work"? Did you get a compiler error? If so, what does it say? If not, did you also change `CreateRenderTarget()`'s signature as I suggest in the answer?

Answer (score 0):

This is a very strange code. You are passing everything by value, and expect to modify the value in the function.

If you plan to modify the pointer that is passed to the function, the prototype should as follows:

void CreateRenderTarget(HWND, ID2D1HwndRenderTarget*& pRT);